# SSRS - Blank pdf page when sub tablix doens't fit the page

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

My report works fine when I view it online.
When I save it to a pdf, then it works fine when everything fits the A4 page.

When it doesn't, my issue starts:
Suddenly my Notes Row Group becomes much wider and this is triggering an empty page.

The Tablix10 is inside another Tablix2, see screenshots.

[image]
[image]

I placed them inside a rectangle with that rectangle as the parent.

Both Tablixes have the KeepTogether as False.

When I run the report everything looks great:
[image]

But when I save it as a pdf, then it goes fine, when the Notes fits the page.

[image]

But bad, when the Notes row doesn't fit the page anymore.
You can see that this column now became much broader than before, and this is triggering an empty page.

[image]

Any idea why?